# show/hide green tick upon input field change

Tags: javascript

I wont put the whole code, since i think it doesnt matter, because the problem is js related. I have a form and input fields(2 password fields). With css i made a "green tick" next to these fields. I want these green ticks to appear when BOTH fields are equal, and re-appear when i delete one "character" from one of the fields - when they are not equal.

pswd1/pswd2 - my input pass fields

I want the green ticks to show when they are equal and when the length of the second field(the confirmation one) is greater than 6

```
$('#pswd1').on('change', function(){
   pass = $('#pswd1').val();
   pass1 = $("#pswd2").val();
   if(pass = pass1 && pass1.length > 6){
       $("#gtick1").show();``
       $("#gtick2").show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `=`, you are assigning the value from one variable to another inside the condition, to compare you should use `==` or `===`. Also I will prefer `input` event instead of `change` here.

Try the following way:

```js
$('#pswd1, #pswd2').on('input', function(){
   var pass = $('#pswd1').val();
   var pass1 = $("#pswd2").val();
   if(pass == pass1 && pass1.length > 6){
     $("#gtick1, #gtick2").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#gtick1, #gtick2").hide();
   }
});
```

```css
span{
  color: green; 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="pswd1">
<span id="gtick1">✔</span><br>
<input type="password" id="pswd2">
<span id="gtick2">✔</span>
```

Comment: thank u very much, i saw where my mistake were - $('#pswd1, #pswd2'). I wasnt targeting both fields, and thats why i saw no response.

Answer (score 0):

```
pass = pass1
```

should be

```
pass === pass1
```

You have some wild `` in there too. Throw a `console.log('hi')` in at the top to make sure the code is actually being run and you should be gucci.

Answer (score 0):

you can play around this code. Though it's not exactly what you want but it will serve your purpose

```js
$('#pswd1, #pswd2').on('keyup', function(){

   pass1 = $('#pswd1').val();
   pass2 = $("#pswd2").val();
   if(pass1 === pass2){
         $("#passDiv1").css("background-color", "green");
         $("#passDiv2").css("background-color", "green");
     }else{
         $("#passDiv1").css("background-color", "yellow");
         $("#passDiv2").css("background-color", "yellow");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="passDiv1" style="padding: 5px">
  <input id="pswd1" type="password"/>
</div>
<div id="passDiv2" style="padding: 5px">
  <input id="pswd2" type="password"/>
</div>
```